# MySQL IN clause using sub-select versus list of values

Tags: mysql, performance

I have two levels of filtering I need to do on some related data. The first query looks something like:

```
SELECT t1.fk_id 
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t3.fk_id = t1.fk_id
WHERE t1.field1 > 10 AND t3.field2 = Y
```

The second query runs against another table with the same fk_id field, and looks something like

```
SELECT t2.fk_id, SUM(t2.field3) AS sum_3, SUM(t2.field_4) AS sum_4 
FROM t2 
WHERE fk_id IN (fk_values_from_query_1)
GROUP BY t2.fk_id
HAVING sum_3 > 1000
```

Now, I can run this 2 different ways, from what I can tell - though I'm not tied to either method, any open to other methods as well. I could either embed the first query into the second query as a SUB-SELECT, which I understand to be really bad from a performance perspective. Or, I could extract the values from the results of query 1, and embed them as a list in query 2 (in my application code).

The two parts to this question are:

1. Is there any difference, performance wise, between the 2 query structures described above?
2. Is there a better way to structure these 2 queries?

**Benchmarks**

I didn't fully test this, but ran my version, and the version posted by Barmar, against my data. My query was running in approximately 4.23 seconds, while Barmar's version took only 0.60 seconds to run. That's an 85% improvement!

Comment: Remember for performance the best and only answer is: **benchmarking**. The type of data you're manipulating, the MySQL configuration, the properties of the hardware you're on, they will have a massive impact on the performance of any query.

Comment: Absolutely! But I don't know enough about the theory of these queries to know which methods are "known" to be inefficient. As our DB has not been fine-tuned afaik, "standard theory" will likely cover my case.

Comment: If you're concerned about speed, you need to benchmark. I've tried things that on the surface seemed absurd, just one of ten different approaches, but which somehow massively outperformed all the others. MySQL is an unpredictable beast. If both those approaches produce the correct data, the next step is to test against actual production data if possible, or a realistic facsimile if possible.

Comment: Will do - is there any other method you can think of that might work for this? I see the version from @Barmar below that uses a subselect joined to the outer query, rather than using an "IN" - will benchmark those 3 versions, see what they produce.

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM t1, t2` instead of a `JOIN`, perhaps. I'm curious what the results of your testing will be.

Comment: In theory, the nested subselect, a static list derived from such a  query done ahead of time, a join as shown should all perform similarly. In practice they often do. If there's something skewed about the data, where the DBMS's assumptions are turning out to be wrong, you might find one will work better than another. Another approach can be to use an EXISTS as a sub-select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should combine them using a JOIN:

```
SELECT t2.fk_id, SUM(t2.field3) AS sum_3, SUM(t2.field_4) AS sum_4 
FROM t2
JOIN (SELECT distinct t1.fk_id
      FROM t1
      JOIN t2 ON t3.fk_id = t1.fk_id
      WHERE t1.field1 > 10 AND t3.field2 = 'Y') t4
ON t2.fk_id = t4.fk_id
GROUP BY t2.fk_id
HAVING sum_3 > 1000
```

I've consistently found that MySQL performs horribly on `WHERE col IN (subquery)` queries, compared to the analogous join. I haven't compared it with queries where I substitute the values from the subquery, because I've only done that when it wasn't possible to do it in a single query (e.g. I need to match data on different servers).

BTW, there's no point in using a `LEFT JOIN` if you're also filtering on values in the table being joined with.

In all cases, make sure that you have indexes on the keys used in the join or `IN` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the additional approach. And your comment regarding the JOIN is well taken.

Comment: Sometimes you can even add the fields in the where clause for added effect. However, in the case your t3.field2 might only have two values 'Y' or 'N', adding this to the index would be pretty pointless. But sometimes on some RDBMSs/situations this could improve the chances of your index being used.

Comment: Right, you usually only need indexes on columns that reduce the number of rows significantly. A Y/N field may just cut the number of rows in half, which doesn't help much. It could be useful to have it as part of a composite index, though.

Comment: As a note: performance of this query, versus my version, on my production DB ran in 0.6031 seconds, better by a factor of almost 10 - my query took 4.2331 seconds to run.