# MySQL Query show results based on multiple filters/tags

Tags: mysql, sql

This has been asked in different ways before, but I can't seem to get something that works for what I need exactly.

The goal here is to make a search query that returns Photos based on tags that are selected.  Many tags can be applied to the filter simultaneously, which would need to make it so that the query only returns photos that have ALL of the tags selected.  Think of any major web shop where you are narrowing down results after performing a basic keyword search.

Table1: Photos
    ID|Title|Description|URL|Created

Table2: PhotosTagsXref
    ID|PhotoId|TagId

Table3: PhotosTags
    ID|Title|Category

What I have:

```
SELECT p.* FROM `PhotosTagsXref` AS pt
LEFT JOIN `Photos` AS p ON p.`ID` = pt.`PhotoId`
LEFT JOIN `PhotosTags` AS t ON pt.`TagId` = t.`ID`
WHERE p.`Description` LIKE "%test%" AND 
????
GROUP BY p.`ID`
ORDER BY p.`Created` DESC LIMIT 20
```

The ???? is where I've tried a bunch of things, but stumped.  Problem is I can easily find a result set that contains photos with one tag or another, but if applying 2, 3, or 4 tags we'd need to only return photos that have entries for all of those tags in the database. I think this will involve combining result sets but not 100% sure.

Example:
Photo 1 Tags: Blue, White, Red
Photo 2 Tags: Blue

Searching for a photo with tags of 'blue' returns both photos, searching for a photo with tags of 'blue' and 'white' returns only Photo 1.

Comment: Maybe the CONTAINS clause will help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL in-operator must match all values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505045/mysql-in-operator-must-match-all-values)

Comment: I'd use an inner join to a subselect statement.  How are you building this query and how are you taking inputs?  If there is an upper limit to the number of tags, then you can do a SQL only statement here.  If you have no limit to tags, you'll need to be a bit more dynamic in how you build your sql statement.

Comment: Inner join per the solution below did the trick, thanks.   The query is built from a GET request, contains a filter array variable with a theoretically limitless number of tags.  There is a logical limit, but I guess it could be into the 10 - 20 range.

Comment: I put it in my answer...but just a warning on MySQL...it does not handle subselects well at all (it's so poorly evaluated by the query engine).  Where exists performs better than where in, but if you expect this database to grow any, I'd be very wary of implementing subqueries in MySQL (my solution to this issue is to use Postgres instead of MySQL :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admittedly a bit ugly. But assuming that PhotosTags.Category has the 'Blue', 'White', etc, try something along this line.

```
SELECT p.* 
From `Photos` AS p
WHERE p.`Description` LIKE "%test%" AND 
  AND Exists
      ( Select 1 FROM `PhotosTagsXref` AS pt
        Inner JOIN `PhotosTags` AS t ON pt.`TagId` = t.`ID`
        Where pt.`PhotoId` = p.`ID`
          And t.Category = 'FirstCatToSearch'
      )   
  AND Exists
      ( Select 1 FROM `PhotosTagsXref` AS pt
        Inner JOIN `PhotosTags` AS t ON pt.`TagId` = t.`ID`
        Where pt.`PhotoId` = p.`ID`
          And t.Category = 'SecondCatToSearch'
      )   
  AND Exists
      ( ...
      )   
      ...
```

Comment: This did the trick, maybe not pretty like you said but it works. Speed doesn't seem abnormal either.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing the requested set of tags is (`red`,`blue`) you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM `Photos` 
WHERE `Description` LIKE "%test%" 
AND `ID` IN (
  SELECT pt.`PhotoId` FROM `PhotosTagsXref` AS pt
  JOIN `PhotosTags` AS t ON pt.`TagId` = t.`ID`
  WHERE t.Title in ('red','blue') /* your set here */
  GROUP BY pt.`PhotoId` HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.`TagId`)=2 /* # of tags */
  )
ORDER BY `Created` DESC LIMIT 20
```

Apparently, the tag set needs to be created dynamically, as well as its count.

*Note*: I'm counting `DISTINCT` `TagID`s because I don't know your table's constraints. If `PhotosTagsXRef` had a PK/UNIQUE (`PhotoId`,`TagId`) and `PhotosTags` had a PK/UNIQUE (`TagId`), then `COUNT(*)` would suffice.

Comment: Thanks. Work for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.* FROM `PhotosTagsXref` AS pt
LEFT JOIN `Photos` AS p ON p.`ID` = pt.`PhotoId`
LEFT JOIN `PhotosTags` AS t ON pt.`TagId` = t.`ID`
inner join (select PhotoId from PhotosTagsXref 
             LEFT JOIN `PhotosTags` AS t 
             ON pt.`TagId` = t.`ID`
             where (t.title = 'cond 1' or t.title = 'cond 2' ...)
             --where t.title in (list condition)    **this works as well**
             having count(1) = (count of conditions) ) filter
  on filter.photoID = pt.PhotoID
WHERE p.`Description` LIKE "%test%"
GROUP BY p.`ID`
ORDER BY p.`Created` DESC LIMIT 20
```

That should work, I made some assumptions on what column to use for the filter and joins, you may need to retool...the inner join functions as a filter and should pull out only records that have the number of matches equal to the total of the number of matches submitted.  Now you just need a language to plug in those conditions and condition count values.

Comment: This might work also but I wasn't able to adapt it correctly, perhaps my fault, but the other solution did the trick for me.

Comment: Just a warning...MYSQL has some known performance issues with subselects.  The where exists usage here does optimize it, but if you start hitting performance issues with your MySQL queries, the series of if exists statements is the likely culprit. couple links... http://www.mysqldbahelp.com/2010/03/subselect-vs-join-performanace.html#!/2010/03/subselect-vs-join-performanace.html   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16403860/mysql-in-clause-using-sub-select-versus-list-of-values

Comment: Performance could be an issue down the line so I'll be sure to look at that, joins are usually my preference as well I just couldn't wrap my head around this one for some reason.

Comment: Yes, I got bit by that with MySQL in the past, figured you should get that heads up.  I did a change to my answer that might be simpler.  Where t.title in (list conditions) will work as well as the or statement I used.

Comment: One final question, about this part: (count of conditions), can you give an example of what that should actually be? I think I have the rest of this worked out then I can mark this as a good solution also.

Comment: What are your users using to submit these queries?  I'd think that would be the easiest place to take the 'count of conditions' value from.

Comment: They are just clicking checkboxes in a sidebar for various filters, variables are coming through in an array from a filter GET variable from a form.

Comment: PHP?  I think count() works there.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php  (I'm getting prompted to move from comments to chat, but zach isn't high enough rep.  I'd report it, but Meta appears full of people saying the same ;)  )